# Library Override Rig Only

Tags: animation, blend-files, linked-data, data-blocks, library-overrides

I'm linking a character to a new file and I will be posing/animating it in that file. And that character will be duplicated many times and posed differently *(like an army for example).*

**My question is:** Is it possible to only override the rig, and keep the mesh objects/collections as **linked** and not **overridden**?

When I try to override the rig object only, the rest of the related collections change with it, which is a problem because blender considers them as actual objects and not linked data **(They are still linked in terms of being un-editable, and getting updated when I make changes in their source file, the size of the file increases)**, and it gets slower and the .blend file size increases with each duplicate, despite using duplicate linked option, and the scene becomes extremely slow, and just the process of posing the character becomes a nightmare, Let alone animating it.

And even though I set up proxy collections, it doesn't make a difference, even if I hide/disable all collections.